# Pegar pegar ultimo resultado e incrementar com php, javascript e mysql

Tags: php, javascript, java, mysql

Como que faço para pegar o ultimo valor inserido na SPAN e somar mais 10 para salvar no BD, a inserção está tudo ok, preciso eliminar o input e cada vez que inserir no BD soma mais 10.
Exemplo:
Produto 100 ao clicar no botão, Produto 110 assim por diante, sem refresh tipo site de leilão de 1 centavo.
Montei este script abaixo e esta funcionado a inserção, mas cliente coloca o valor que quiser, preciso eliminar a input e somar os valores ao clicar no botão
Obrigado Pessoal.....

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#load_button').click(function(){
  var valor_txt = $('#valor').val(); 
  if($.trim(valor_txt) != '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"produtos/insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{arremate:valor_txt},
    dataType:"text",
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#valor').val("");
    }
   });
  }
 });
 
 setInterval(function(){
  $('#load_price').load("produtos/arremate.php").fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000);
 
});
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" class="form-control" /> <!-- envia valor para o DB -->
<input type="button" name="load_button" id="load_button"  value="valor" class="btn btn-info" />

<span class="item_price" name="load_price" id="load_price"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você poderia remover o input usando javascript quando clicar.

```js
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}
// Use no evento
function my() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("valor").remove();
}
```